# Is the unique subobject also mono?

Tags: category-theory, monomorphisms

Suppose
    $u : S → A$ and $v : T → A$
with codomain $A$ are monomorphisms, we write $u ≤ v$ if $u$ factors through $v$—that is, if there exists $φ : S → T$ such that $u = v ∘ φ$. I understand that such a $\varphi$ is unique. But is it also a **monomorphism**? Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to know if $\varphi\circ x = \varphi\circ y \implies x=y$. Post-compose both sides of the antecedent with $v$.

Comment: Which of the following chain of implications is the right one?

[1] $(\varphi\circ x = \varphi\circ y \implies(v\circ\varphi\circ x = v\circ\varphi\circ y) ) \implies x=y$

OR

[2] $\varphi\circ x = \varphi\circ y \implies(v\circ\varphi\circ x = v\circ\varphi\circ y \implies x=y)$